# How to play audio from audio array on click in xml in android

Tags: android

```
     public void getSound(String file) {
                    MediaPlayer mp;
                        try{
                            String SoundFile=file;
                            System.out.println("Here is the File"+SoundFile);
                            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Uri.parse("android.resource://himanshu.sound/raw/"+file)); 
                            mp.start(); 
                            System.out.println("PLAYED");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("Exception->"+e);
                        }   
                }
```

This is my code file name is game.mp3 comming from assets.

Now I want to the audio to be played

This is my xml

```
    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/soundbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:onClick="getSound"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/audio" />



mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Uri.parse("android.resource://himanshu.sound/raw/"+file));
```

in this line i am having error

getActivity().getBaseContext()  i think proper thing must be there

Answer (score 0):

You''d better have an ImageButton

```
                  <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/soundbtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/audio" />
```

and the OnClick method has to be with a different signature

```
public final void onClick(View v) {

    // todo ............
     }
```

Comment: mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Uri.parse("android.resource://himanshu.sound/raw/"+file)); 

I ma getting error in this line